# i want to line all theses divs horizontaly side by side

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is my css. I tried using position relative and then left "x%" right "x%":

```
#africa{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color:#33CC33;display: none;}
#asia{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #FF6600;display: none; position:}
#australia{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #FF5050;display: none;}
#europe{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #666699;display: none; }
#north-america{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #CC0000;display: none; }
#south-america{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #003300;display: none; }

#africa1{width:16%}
#asia1{width:16%}
#australia1{width:16%}
#europe1{width:16%}
#na1{width:16%}
#sa1{width:16%}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<button id="africa1">Africa</button>
<div id="africa"></div>
<button id="asia1">Asia</button>
<div id="asia"></div>
<button id="australia1">Australia</button>
<div id="australia"></div>
<button id="europe1">Europe</button>
<div id="europe"></div>
<button id="na1">North-america</button>
<div id="north-america"></div>
<button id="sa1">South-america</button>
<div id="south-america"></div>
```

i have been trying to figure out this problem for nearly two hours. can someone please help?

Comment: But you have the `<div>` elements all set to `display: none;`, so they are not rendered

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you float your div's left.

Add in your css `float:left;` for each element you want to display side by side.

Could you describe what you want this to look like? I am a little confused... Do you want the buttons in the div? Or are you trying to use the div's as spacer's? If that's the case, I would recommend using padding or margins on the buttons